# What's the efficient way to select correct data from this table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is the table I have

```
ID  Key     Value   Lang 
1   key1    text1   en
2   key2    text2   en
3   key3    text3   en
4   key1    chu1    vi
5   key2    chu2    vi
```

When select the "vi" lang, missing keys will be selected from the "en" lang
Basically the result should be

```
4   key1    chu1    vi
5   key2    chu2    vi
3   key3    text3   en
```

Is there an efficient way to get the result without complex query like this?

```
WITH cte_data
AS (
    SELECT ID
        ,Key
        ,Value
        ,Lang
    FROM tblSysText
    WHERE Lang = 'vi'
    )
SELECT ID
    ,Key
    ,Value
    ,Lang
FROM cte_data

UNION

SELECT ID
    ,Key
    ,Value
    ,Lang
FROM tblSysText
WHERE Lang = 'en'
    AND Key NOT IN (
        SELECT Key
        FROM cte_data
        )
```

Thanks.

---

Update the data set
Here is what similar to the real data
Basically the table contains the text of several different languages

What I want is to select all the keys and values of a specific language.
Then select the missing keys and values from the "en" language

```
ID  Key     Value   Lang 
1   key1    text1   en
2   key2    text2   en
3   key3    text3   en
4   key1    chu1    vi
5   key2    chu2    vi
6   key4    chu4    vi
7   key4    text4   en
8   key5    text5   en
9   key5    s5      ye
10  key6    s6      ZW
```

Here is the expected output when select for "vi" language

```
ID  Key     Value   Lang
4   key1    chu1    vi
5   key2    chu2    vi
6   key4    chu4    vi
3   key3    text3   en
8   key5    text5   en
```

Comment: Please show us the real data, including the timestamp column.

Comment: I don't think it's related to the ID or the timestamp.
Sometimes the "vi" is created first, then the "en"
Basically I need to select everything in "vi", and then the "en" that don't exist in "vi" collection

Comment: You need some column which keeps track of the order of creation.  There is no internal order to the records you pasted above.

Comment: Please see the updated dataset

Comment: What is the expected output from the new data set and why?

Comment: I've added the expected output from the new data. 
It's for a multi-language web pages, or "localization", I'm not sure which term can be used.
What I want is to select all the keys and values of a specific language. Then select the missing keys and values from the "en" language.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `ROW_NUMBER` along with a `TOP 1 WITH TIES` trick here:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES ID, [Key], Value, Lang
FROM tblSysText
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Key] ORDER BY Lang DESC);
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

The logic here is to retain, for each key, the record with the "highest" language value.  For those keys having both `en` and `vi` records, it would choose the latter record, otherwise it would default to choosing the former.

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work for the real data. Sometimes I have the "vi" created first, not the "en"

Comment: If you are looking for the "first" one, then you should be ordering in row number using that timestamp column, so use something like: `ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Key] ORDER BY latest_timestamp DESC)`

Comment: Not really the first one. Basically select everything in "vi", and then the "en" that don't exist in "vi" collection

Comment: @comXyz: What makes you think this query doesn't work? Have you tried it? The query gets you one row per key. It gets you the vi row when available, otherwise the en row. Isn't this exactly what you want?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner The OP seems to want this result set, but because the `vi` records are older than the `en` ones.

Comment: Please see the updated dataset @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: @comXyz: So there are other languages in the table. Then you first need to restrict the result to the two languages you are interested in (e.g. 'vi' and 'en'), as shown in Popeye's answer `WHERE Lang IN ('en', 'vi')`. Next thing you need to adjust to is for the alphabetical order no longer being sufficient (e.g. 'de' < 'en' < 'vi'): `ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Key] ORDER BY CASE WHEN Lang = 'en' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use analytical function `row_number` as follows:

```
select * from
(SELECT ID
    ,Key
    ,Value
    ,Lang
    ,row_number() over (partition by key order by Lang desc) as rn
FROM tblSysText
WHERE Lang in ('en','vi')) t
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

> When select the "vi" lang, missing keys will be selected from the "en" lang

You can also express this using `not exists`:

```
select st.*
from tblSysText st
where st.lang = 'vi' or
      (st.lang = 'en' and
       not exists (select 1
                   from tblSysText st2
                   where st2.key = st.key and
                         st2.lang = 'vi'
                  )
      );
```

With an index on `tblSysText(key, lang)`, I would expect this to have somewhat better performance than solutions using window functions.